# gulp script not generating css file in .net project

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, sass, gulp

I am using gulp on a .net project and for some reason the script isnt generating the css file.

Here is my folder structure for the root folder and assets folder:

[image]

[image]

Here is my gulp script:

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
var gulp          = require('gulp');
var sass          = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer  = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./wwwroot/sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/css/'))
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);
```

The script runs fine with no errors, but the css file is not created. Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: Try removing `./` in front of `wwwroot` for both the `.src` and `.dest` since your gulpfile is running from the same directory

Comment: i did try this, i get the same results

Comment: Run a watch task for a save event for a test: `gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.watch('wwwroot/sass/*.scss', ['styles']).on('change', function (event) {
        console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
    });});` This should give you a message to let you know if it's running.

Comment: Another thing to try is to require `gulp-if` and then put this right after your last `pipe` (the dest) `.pipe(gulpif(config.notifyActive, notify({
            onLast: true,
            message: 'CSS Compiled'
        })));`

Comment: nothing! not quite sure whats going on

Comment: Try replacing `['sass']` with `gulp.series('sass')`

Comment: If you are getting nothing, then I'm guessing your gulp file isn't running. Weird!

Comment: What is your gulp version: `gulp -v`?